# Undefined reference to `WinMain' in C++ while exceuting on vectors

Tags: c++

I have to calculate the longest prefix string in the program. I am using c++ for this and I don't actually know extensively about vector and its functions.

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

class Solution {
public:
    void longestCommonPrefix(vector<string>& strs) 
    {
        string ans;
        strs.size(); //no of rows
        strs.push_back("flower");
        strs.push_back("flower");

        string one=strs[0];
        string two=strs[1];

        int oneL=one.length();
        int twoL=two.length();

        int min=oneL<twoL?oneL:twoL;

        for(int i=0;i<min;i++)
        {
            char temp=one[i];

            if(temp==two[i] )
            ans=ans+temp;
        }

        
    }
    
};
```

This displays an error of winMain and I do understand it must be related to the main function but the problem is I cannot put nain() function here else it displays an error again. Thus, I cannot put a main function and I if I don't I face an error.

Help me out stackmates.

Comment: Were you trying to put `main` inside the class? You can't do that either, it has to be in global scope

Comment: What compiler are you using?  You need to set it to target a Windows console application, not a Windows application.  And then you need a `main` function.

Comment: WinMain error is due to the fact that you do not have a main function to execute. Try adding a main function and creating an object, then calling the function using the object.Also main should be global.

Comment: The posted code is just a class with a member function. But the class never gets instantiated, and the member function never gets called. So you'll need to add some other code to actually use and call those.